# Overlapping Photos with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, photo

https://codepen.io/nhn34/pen/zVQyWG

I'm trying to overlap 3 photos using CSS Grid. This is the outcome that I want:

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTgCx.png)

I tried following these tutorials that both uses the same method but they didn't work for me: https://www.superhi.com/video/overlapping-layouts-with-css-grid, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZJrcOfBaNY

The results that I get looks like in CodePen and I don't know where I did wrong!

These are my code:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  div:first-child {
    grid-column: 2 / span 3;
  }
  div:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
  div:last-child {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <img src="img/cancer/face1.svg" alt="face1">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/cancer/cancer.jpg" alt="cancer">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/cancer/point1.svg" alt="point1">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: For starters you're pen is set to CSS but the styles are written in SCSS format. Change the pre-processor setting by clicking the little gear icon, top-left of css pane.

Answer (score 0):

you only missed specifing grid-row property

```
grid-row: 1;
```

good luck